# Sql query with special characters - how to handle?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-like

I've few emp names like

> 1. john,1
> 2. devil's
> 3. corn

something like this

Now when i'm searching for these names I'm using

```
select * from emp where empname like ('john,1,devil's,corn')
```

But I'm not getting expected values also I'm getting error because emp name contains special charecters like , and '.

Can someone help me out how to solve this?

Comment: What version of SQL (Oracle, MYSQL, Microsoft SQL)

Comment: sorry i'm using sql server 2005

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes you have 3 discrete names in your example string

Exact match. you need to double up quotes.

```
select * from emp where
empname IN ('john,1' , 'devil''s', 'corn')
```

You can't LIKE/IN in SQL Server too.

```
select * from emp where
  empname like '%john,1%'
  OR
  empname like '%devil''s%'
  OR
  empname like '%corn%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from emp where empname like ('john\,1','devil\'s','corn\'') escape '\'
```

use keyword **escape** to mention escape character for the query.

Answer (score 1):

if you use mysql:

```
select * from emp where empname like ('john,1','devil\'s','corn')
```

Comment: i think that for sql server u can escaping single quote by '' (two single qoute) instead of \'...

Answer (score 1):

For most versions of SQL, you need to escape the single quote, for example.

```
select * from emp where empname like ('john,1,devil''s,corn')
```

Also, the above example is looking for a very specific string value, you need to include * or ? as wildcard characters, so to look for all empname's like devil's, use

```
select * from emp where empname like '%devil''s%'
```

Another example

```
select * from emp where empname like 'john,1%'
```

Comment: * is not a valid SQL wildcard (at least not a standard one)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an empname of "devil's" then I agree with the use of the escape character that Sachin and Ratinho used.

However, the `like` clause is used for something that is like another. For example, if you are looking for something that starts with "devil's" then you might use

```
select * from emp where empname like ('devil\'s%')
```

which would match

```
devil's peak
devil's beard
devil's
```

but not

```
Devil's peak
deviled eggs
devil
```

If you want to match an empname with "devil's" in the middle, then you might use

```
select * from emp where empname like ('%devil\'s%')
```