# List of special characters that not work in sqlite query?

Tags: android, sqlite

how can find a list of special characters that should not use in sqlite query or using that(') giving me exception like this

> android.database.sqlite.**SQLiteException**: near "name": syntax error
>   (code 1)

Comment: Your problem is probably not a special character, but that is impossible to determine without the actual query.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the following links. It is a possible duplicate.

[Sql query with special characters - how to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875015/sql-query-with-special-characters-how-to-handle)
http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries

Comment: I am asking for how many characters that we should know in sqlite query, i have find only " ' ". and DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(name) is also not working.