# Putting output from sql query into another query using R environment

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I am wondering what approach should have been selected to perform action from title. I am using ODBC connection and what I get from first sql query are like 40-50 rows in one column. What I want is to put this output as a values **in** to search for.

How should i treat this? Like a array or separated variables? I still do not know R well so just need to know where to search for.

Regards

------more explanation below----

I have list of 40-50 numbers of 10 digits each, organized in a column.

I am trying to do this:

```
list <- c(my_input)
sql_in <- paste0(list, collapse="")
```

and characters are organized like this after this operations:

```
'c(1234567890, , 1234567890, 1234567890)'
```

and almost all looks fine and fit into my query besides additional c character at the beginning and missing apostrophes.I try to use gsub function but did not work in way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
list<-c("try","this") #The output from your first query

sql_in<-paste0(list, collapse="','")
```

The Output

```
paste("select * from table where table.var in ",paste("('",sql_in,"')",sep=''))
[1] "select * from table where table.var in  ('try','this')"
```

If yuo have space as first or last element of the string you can use this code:

```
`list<-c(" first element is a space","try","this","last element is a space ")` #The output from your first query
```

Find space at first or last character

```
first_space<-substr(list, start = 1, stop = 1)==" "
last_space<-substr(list, start = nchar(list), stop = nchar(list))==" "
```

Remove spaces

```
list[first_space]<-substr(list[first_space], start = 2, stop = nchar(list[first_space]))
list[last_space]<-substr(list[last_space], start = 1, stop = nchar(list[last_space])-1)

sql_in<-paste0(list, collapse="','")
```

Your output

```
paste0("select * from table where table.var in ",paste("('",sql_in,"')",sep=''))
"select * from table where table.var in ('first element is a space','try','this','last element is a space')"
```

Comment: this is really helpful. I have almost got what is needed but still have problem because I need these values in accaptable format for sql in commant. It means we are missing apostrophes and commas. Could you share with me some method which works in R? I only found function sub which is not working how i want to. 

And other issue is that this list is still containing letter c on the beginning.

Comment: I don't understand exactly your problem. Can you provide a sample of your dataset or your R code? This is the best way to fix your problems.

Comment: Ok, you almost solved my problem, function paste( "Select * from table where header in (",paste((sql_in),")")) is working as I want only can not execute is as sql query using ODBC becouse of missing parenthesis. I am trying to put it in using various functions but nothing is working. Is it even possible to have such character as ' in a record?

Comment: ' is a special character, you have to handle it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875015/sql-query-with-special-characters-how-to-handle

Comment: What's your error doing this: sqlQuery(channel,paste("select * from table where table.var in ",paste("('",sql_in,"')",sep='')))

Comment: I am using for now paste( "Select * from table where table.var in ('",paste((sql_in),"'",")")) and uotput generated is almost what I want. The issue is that first variable from my sql_in table inserted into psate function hsa a space between ' and variable, and last one also has a space between variable and '. Tried to change syntax but without results.

Comment: Added more details on the answer according to this. Let me know!

Comment: Yes, it worked :) Did some workaround but finally managed with paste and gsub functions. Anyway thank you for your help :)

'sql_in <- gsub(" ", "" ,paste(entity_1[,1],sep = "",collapse = "','"))
sql_in <- paste( "('",paste((sql_in),"')"))
sql_in <- gsub(" ", "",sql_in) 
query_6 <- paste( "Select * from table where condition in",paste((sql_in),""))'

Comment: Perfect! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You may likely do this in one SQL call using a subquery.  Notice in the call below that the result of

```
SELECT n_gear
FROM Gear
WHERE n_gear IN (3,4)
```

Is passed to the `WHERE` clause of the primary query. This is perfectly valid and will allow your query to execute entirely in SQL without having to do any intermediate steps in R.

(I use `sqldf` for simplicity of illustration, but this should work through just about any ODBC connection)

```
library(sqldf)

Gear <- data.frame(n_gear = 1:5)

sqldf(
  "SELECT mpg, qsec, gear, wt
   FROM mtcars 
   WHERE gear IN (SELECT n_gear 
                  FROM Gear 
                  WHERE n_gear IN (3,4))"
)
```

Comment: thanks for this solution, I am often using this in sql but in R getting error "Could not  SQLAlllocStmt". And I do not want to specify a range becouse number of rows can vary and I belive after clause WHERE must be something but thats not a problem. maybe it might be caused due to lcak of ' '? Anyway like this solution, will try to work a little on it.

Comment: Regarding dynamic range this works: ``rng <- 3:4; fn$sqldf(
  "SELECT mpg, qsec, gear, wt
   FROM mtcars 
   WHERE gear IN (SELECT n_gear 
                  FROM Gear 
                  WHERE n_gear IN (`toString(rng)`))")``  The `fn$` part comes from the gsubfn package (which sqldf pulls in) but also works to insert strings into any the argument of any function, not just into `sqldf`.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are expecting some thing like shown below code,

```
data <- dbGetQuery(con, "select column from yourfirsttable")

list <- paste(data$column, collapse="','")

result <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = sprintf("select * from yourresulttable where inv in ('%s')",list))
```

Comment: Got the output ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear exactly what you're wanting to achieve here. For example, one use case just means you can do it all with a join. But I have cases where I don't know the values for the test without doing some computation. Then I do a separate query having created a query string thus:

```
> id <- 1:5
> paste0("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (", paste0(id, collapse = ","), ")")
[1] "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)"
```